# MVC.NET Routing works in development server but not on IIS 7.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

I've upgraded our project from being a website to a web app and imported to VS2k10.

I've added the following references:

System.Web.Abstractions

System.Web.MVC

System.Web.Routing
...

Changed target framework to 4.0...

Added a controller 'HomeController.cs'... This now works in the development server but NOT in IIS 7.0

Windows Server 2k8 r2
VS2010
.net framework 4.0

Application pool is running in Integrated Pipeline mode... I'm a little confused over why it works in the dev server but not on IIS...

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <add name="ErrorHandlerModule" type="System.Web.Mobile.ErrorHandlerModule, System.Web.Mobile, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" preCondition="managedHandler" />
        <add name="ServiceModel" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule, System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" preCondition="managedHandler" />
        <add name="Page" type="Impark.MPS.SelfServe.UIL.GlobalPageEvents, PageEventsModule" preCondition="managedHandler" />

    </modules>
    <handlers>
        <add name="*.vbhtml_*" path="*.vbhtml" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0" />
        <add name="*.vbhtm_*" path="*.vbhtm" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0" />
        <add name="*.cshtml_*" path="*.cshtml" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0" />
        <add name="*.cshtm_*" path="*.cshtm" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0" />
        <add name="*.aspq_*" path="*.aspq" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0" />
        <add name="*.xamlx_*" path="*.xamlx" verb="*" type="System.Xaml.Hosting.XamlHttpHandlerFactory, System.Xaml.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0" />
        <add name="*.xoml_*" path="*.xoml" verb="*" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpHandler, System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0" />
        <add name="*.rules_*" path="*.rules" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0" />
        <add name="*.svc_*" path="*.svc" verb="*" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpHandler, System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0" />
        <add name="*.soap_*" path="*.soap" verb="*" type="System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Http.HttpRemotingHandlerFactory, System.Runtime.Remoting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0" />
        <add name="*.rem_*" path="*.rem" verb="*" type="System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Http.HttpRemotingHandlerFactory, System.Runtime.Remoting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0" />
        <add name="*.asmx_*" path="*.asmx" verb="*" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0" />
        <add name="ScriptResource.axd_GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" verb="GET,HEAD" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0" />
        <add name="*_AppService.axd_*" path="*_AppService.axd" verb="*" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0" />
        <add name="eurl.axd_*" path="eurl.axd" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0" />
    </handlers>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
</system.webServer>
```

Sorry, forgot to mention.  On dev server I get the expected response.  Same URL in IIS I get:
 Error Summary
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Comment: Have you made sure you have moved all the necessary files to the failing machine.  The error is stating it couldn't find the file?

Comment: Same physical machine and same path... IE there's no moving of files... But I just found a clue... When I add a virtual server path in dev server it fails now too...  IE http://localhost:9999/Home works... But http://localhost:9999/Company.project.SubProject.Target/Home doesn't

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .Net 4.0 you should remove runtimeVersionv2.0 from your preCondition